# Optimal solution to sum of digits problem

Tags: c, algorithm

For a given number `a`, I have to find a number less than `a` (call it `b`) whose digit-sum plus `b` is equal to `a`. `a` can be a negative number.

Example:

```
findB(41)        = 34, [34 + 3 + 4 = 41]
findB(-145)      = -140, [-140 + (-1) + (-4) + 0 = -145]
findB(14)        = 7, [7 + 7 = 14]
findB(11)        = 10, [10 + 1 + 0 = 11]
findB(-101)      = 100, [-100 + (-1) + 0 + 0 = -101]
findB(458962713) = 458962758, [458962758 + 4 + 5 + 8 + 9 + 6 + 2 + 7 + 5 + 8 = 458962713]
```

This is what I have so far but it's not efficient. Also, it doesn't work for odd single-digit numbers (it would have to output a decimal, i.e `findB(1) = 0.5` because `0.5 + 0 + .5 = 1`). I tried to look for a pattern in `i + digitSum(i)` but I couldn't figure it out. Is there a better way?

```
int digitSum(int num) {
  int sum = 0;
  while (num) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
  return sum;
}

int findB(int a) {
  for (int i = 1; i < abs(a); i++) {
    int sum = a < 0 ? i - digitSum(-i) : i + digitSum(i); 
    if (sum == a)
        return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: When you have a = -101 you give 100 as the answer, but this contradicts that b should be less than a.

Comment: `0.5` is not a digit so your example of `findB(1)` returning 0.5 doesn't make sense to me.  Are you expecting us to deal with decimal points when answering this question or can we just focus on integers, and return an error code if there is no solution?  Also, would it be acceptable for an answer to ignore negative numbers?

Comment: @DavidGrayson `findB(a)` has return `b` such that `b + digitSum(b) == a`. `findB(1) = 0.5` because `0.5 + digitSum(0.5) = 1`.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Good point. Didn't see that.

Comment: `digitSum(0.5)` is 0 or 1 because `digitSum` takes an int and the input will get rounded.  Even if you somehow expanded it to handle floats, the only answer that makes sense to return is 5.

Comment: (For positive values of `a`, at least) it would probably be much faster to check values from `a-1` to `1` in descending order rather than from `1` to `a`.

Comment: You can narrow the search space significantly for large `a` by incorporating the knowledge that `digit_sum(b) <= 9 * digit_count(b)`.    It may or may not improve performance to implement `digit_count(b)` as `ceil(log10(b))` (for positive integer `b`).

Comment: Is posted there can't be a solution for any negative number: if `b < a` then adding its negative digits will make `b` even less than `a`.

Comment: You will have to calculate the `digitSum()` just every 10th value as the digit sum will just increase by 1 (starting from the previous `digitSum()`) for every value that is not the 10th value. Digit sum of 10 => 1, then 11 => 2, 12 => 3, ... 20 => 2, 21 => 3, 22 => 4, ...  30 = 3, 31 = 4 etc. Now that I look at it there is even more of pattern there 10 => 1, 20 = 2, 30 => 3, so I believe there is no need to calulate the `digitSum()` with the while loop every time. Don't have more than this observation yet though.

Comment: If `a` is positive can `b` be negative?

Comment: @CraigEstey I guess so.

Comment: There are 10 digits in the entire decimal system, all of them are integers from 0 to 9. No sequence of digits can possibly sum up to 0.5, or to anything negative. If you don't think this is true in the context of your problem, you need to rephrase it, starting with a definition of the term "digit".

Comment: What are the limit for those numbers?

Comment: @tstanisl I don't think there's a limit. Except `a` will never be `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive decimal `int` has at most 10 digits. The sum of them can be at most 9 * 10 = 90. Just brute force looking for numbers between N-90 to N.

Comment: What about numbers with a very large number of digits, like K=100,000,000 digits? They are not normally representable as the C type `int` but the mathematical problem is not phrased in terms of C types. The proposed brute-force solution implemented with a bignum type will not be efficient because it would have to add K digits for each of the 9*K numbers in the range [N-9*K, N], so O(K^2).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.it would be true under assumption that each decrement by 1 is done in O(K) time. However, it is actually O(1) because on average 1.111... digits are changed

Comment: In a math forum, I'd agree. But the problem is tagged with "c". I doubt there's intent that the solution include implementing bignum arithmetic.

Comment: @Gene, maybe, but the OP has not specified the range of K. To me, OP tries to implement `int findB(int a)` what suggests that `int` is sufficient for representing `K`. Therefore I think that the solution is fine.

Comment: Then you need to keep track of which digits are changed, and implement (x+digitSum(x)) such that it works incrementally in O(number of changed digits) on the average. Doable but not exactly easy. I agree that this perhaps extends the original problem to spaces not intended by the author.

Comment: @template boy  I'm surprised you accepted this answer since it doesn't handle negative numbers or floats.  I was trying to get you to say that we didn't need to handle those things in the comments, but you never did.  I hope your next questions have their requirements more clearly defined.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, actually this algorithm can handle negative numbers as well